# Adding words to scikit-learn's CountVectorizer's stop list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, stop-words

Scikit-learn's [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) class lets you pass a string 'english' to the argument stop_words.  I want to add some things to this predefined list.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want the default `'english'` `stop_words` plus some extras of your own?

Comment: this post has been a life saver.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py) for `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`, the full list (actually a `frozenset`, from [`stop_words`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/feature_extraction/_stop_words.py)) of `ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS` is exposed through `__all__`. Therefore if you want to use that list plus some more items, you could do something like:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text 

stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(my_additional_stop_words)
```

(where `my_additional_stop_words` is any sequence of strings) and use the result as the `stop_words` argument. This input to `CountVectorizer.__init__` is parsed by `_check_stop_list`, which will pass the new `frozenset` straight through.

Comment: it's interesting to note there are only 318 stopwords in the set. Maybe these pre-supplied stopwords need to be expanded by the person using it.

Comment: Works very well with CountVectorizer(stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(array_example))

Comment: I tried to use this code but it did not work for me.  Here is a reproducible example:  
my_text = ['John I hope you like it',"Tyler place is near by"]
stop_words =text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union("john")
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
vec = count_vectorizer.fit(my_text)
bag_of_words = vec.transform(my_text)
sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)  #sum_words is a 1xn_words matrix without labels

words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
sublst = sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

sublst still has john

Comment: @seakyourpeak you're not actually _using_ your custom set of stop words...

Comment: Being new to python, I am not able to figure out how I can use it.  I thought 

CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')

means using the stop_words that I already have augmented with my own list.

Thx in advance if you can show in code how to actually use it.

Comment: @seakyourpeak note that the original stop words are a _frozenset_, which is immutable. This creates a _new set_, it doesn't change the old one.

Comment: the updated link to stop_words is: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/feature_extraction/_stop_words.py (had to comment because edit queue was overflowing)