# How to extend the stopwords list with bigrams?

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, stop-words, tfidfvectorizer

I want to use `TfidfVectorizer` for extracting `bigrams`. But extending stopwords list does not works with bigrams. How can I fix this problem?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
import pandas as pd

content = CORPUS
my_stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(['don know', 'good morning', 'happy birthday'])

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=my_stop_words, max_features=25, ngram_range=(2, 2))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(content).todense()
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

I got this warning and nothing changed as a result:

```
Your stop_words may be inconsistent with your preprocessing. Tokenizing the stop words generated tokens ['birthday', 'don', ...] not in stop_words.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove stop phrases/stop ngrams (multi-word strings) using pandas/sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426215/how-to-remove-stop-phrases-stop-ngrams-multi-word-strings-using-pandas-sklearn)

Comment: I'm afraid, I didn't understand that answer!